# Mongo DB find value in array of multiple nested arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to check if an ObjectId exists in a non nested array and in multiple nested arrays, I've managed to get very close using the aggregation framework, but got stuck in the very last step.

My documents have this structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("605ce5f063b1c2eb384c2b7f"),
    "name" : "Test",
    "attrs" : [ 
        ObjectId("6058e94c3994d04d28639616"), 
        ObjectId("6058e94c3994d04d28639627"), 
        ObjectId("6058e94c3994d04d28639622"), 
        ObjectId("6058e94c3994d04d2863962e")
    ],
    "variations" : [ 
        {
            "varName" : "Var1",
            "attrs" : [ 
                ObjectId("6058e94c3994d04d28639616"), 
                ObjectId("6058e94c3994d04d28639627"), 
                ObjectId("6058e94c3994d04d28639622"), 
                ObjectId("60591791d4d41d0a6817d23f")
            ],
        },
        {
            "varName" : "Var2",
            "attrs" : [ 
                ObjectId("60591791d4d41d0a6817d22a"), 
                ObjectId("60591791d4d41d0a6817d255"), 
                ObjectId("6058e94c3994d04d28639622"), 
                ObjectId("60591791d4d41d0a6817d23f")
            ],
        },
    ],
    "storeId" : "9acdq9zgke49pw85"
}
```

Let´s say I need to check if this if this _id exists `"6058e94c3994d04d28639616"` in all arrays named `attrs`.

My aggregation query goes like this:

```
db.product.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          storeId,
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          attrs: 1,
          'variations.attrs': 1,
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          attrs: 1,
          vars: '$variations.attrs',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$vars',
      },
      {
        $project: {
          attr: {
            $concatArrays: ['$vars', '$attrs'],
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

which results in this:

```
  [
    {
      attr: [
        6058e94c3994d04d28639616,
        6058e94c3994d04d28639627,
        6058e94c3994d04d28639622,
        6058e94c3994d04d2863962e,
        6058e94c3994d04d28639616,
        6058e94c3994d04d28639627,
        6058e94c3994d04d28639622,
        60591791d4d41d0a6817d23f,
        60591791d4d41d0a6817d22a,
        60591791d4d41d0a6817d255,
        6058e94c3994d04d28639622,
        60591791d4d41d0a6817d23f
      ]
    },
    {
      attr: [
        60591791d4d41d0a6817d22a,
        60591791d4d41d0a6817d255,
        6058e94c3994d04d28639622,
        60591791d4d41d0a6817d23f,
        6058e94c3994d04d28639624,
        6058e94c3994d04d28639627,
        6058e94c3994d04d28639628,
        6058e94c3994d04d2863963e
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Assuming I have two products in my DB, I get this result. Each element in the outermost array is a different product.

The last bit, which is checking for this key `"6058e94c3994d04d28639616"`, I could not find a way to do it with `$group`, since I dont have keys to group on.
Or with `$match`, adding this to the end of the aggregation:

```
  {
    $match: {
      attr: "6058e94c3994d04d28639616",
    },
  },
```

But that results in an empty array. I know that `$match` does not query arrays like this, but could not find a way to do it with `$in` as well.

Is this too complicated of a Schema? I cannot have the original data embedded, since it is mutable and I would not be happy to change all products if something changed.

Will this be very expensive if I had like 10000 products?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your expected output format when `_id` gets matched?

Comment: Also the query does not produce the "result" in your question.

Comment: I'm expecting anything that would make me check if the key exists or it does not. And this query produces exactly as I posted, I just copy pasted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare string `6058e94c3994d04d28639616` with ObjectId. Convert the string to ObjectId using [`$toObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/) operator when perform `$match` operation like this:

```js
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $in: [{ $toObjectId: "6058e94c3994d04d28639616" }, "$attr"]
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes!! Iwas not including the `$expr ` and this made it work! Thank you very much!